# How to Change placeholder of textBox of search row in radGridView WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, search, gridview, telerik

I'm coding with winForms (c# in visualStudio 2019).

I'm using RadGridView Telerik, and Enable its SearchRow.

In SearchTextBox, there is a default text: "Enter text to search".

I want to change this text. how can I do this?

[image: this text:]

Comment: I don't use Telerik's controls myself but see if [this](https://www.telerik.com/forums/gridview-localization-problems#Xb4nAV4jv0elmlkWJ07fGw) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, using a custom RadGridLocalizationProvider and specifying the RadGridStringId.SearchRowTextBoxNullText is a suitable approach for changing the text in RadGridView. Additional information on how to use the provider is available in the following help article: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/localization/localization